# pass azure synapes notebook name as input name in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I need to pass azure synapse notebook name as input (dynamically) in Azure data factory.

Please assist.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above approach will work for you in synapse and in Azure Data factory as well.
This my repro for your reference.


**In Synapse pipeline:**

**My Synapse Notebook:**


[image]


**Set variable for notebook name:**


[image]


**Notebook activity:**


[image]


**Synapse spark Notebook executed after pipeline execution:**


[image]


**In ADF pipeline:**

In ADF pipeline, you have to create a linked service for Synapse spark notebook. only after that you can access the synapse spark pools and synapse notebooks.

Here also, it supports giving dynamic content and we can give the same as `@variables("variable_name")` for the name of the Notebook as above.


[image]


***NOTE:*** Please make sure you publish your Synapse spark notebook in order to reflect your recent changes. While calling Synapse spark notebook in ADF, make sure you follow these [Prerequisites from Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-synapse-notebook#prerequisites).